# How to integrate CakePHP-app to Facebook canvas

Tags: facebook, cakephp, facebook-canvas

I have problems integrating CakePHP-app (2.3.8) to Facebook canvas. When I load the app-page in Facebook, the answer is:

```
The request has been black-holed
Error: The requested address '/?fb_source=search&ref=ts&fref=ts' was not found on this server.
```

I have defined in Facebook's app settings that my Canvas secure URL is:

```
https://facebook.mydomain.com/
```

So the page is found by Facebook. (actually if the CakePHP's tmp/ directory is not writable, the Facebook's app-page displays the error message about that -> so the URL is at least correct)

I have used Facebook PHP-SDK for integrating to Facebook. My page works as a standalone page, but integrating to Facebook Canvas is the problem.

Here is my Config/facebook.php

```
  $config = array(
    'Facebook' => array(
            'appId' => '***********',
            'secret' => '**********************'
            )
    );
```

And here is my Controller for Facebook related stuff:

```
 public function login() {
            Configure::load('facebook');
            $appId = Configure::read('Facebook.appId');
            $app_secret = Configure::read('Facebook.secret');
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                            'appId' => $appId,
                            'secret'=> $app_secret
            ));
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                            'scope' => 'user_birthday,user_location',
                            'redirect_uri' => BASE_URL . 'books/facebook_connect',
                            'display' => 'popup'
            ));
            $this->redirect($loginUrl);
    }
public function facebook_connect() {
            Configure::load('facebook');
            $appId = Configure::read('Facebook.appId');
            $app_secret = Configure::read('Facebook.secret');
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                            'appId' => $appId,
                            'secret'=> $app_secret
            ));
            $user = $facebook->getUser();

// And the rest of this function is only for saving the authenticated user to the database
```

All the tutorials I have found are pretty straightforward and they make it look so easy to integrate to Facebook canvas. I have not succeeded even in getting the most simple "hello world"-page with only index.php and facebook php-sdk to work. I have tried also with cookies set to true, but that didn't help either.

This is pretty broad question and it must be hard to imagine what could be wrong in my case, but if you can find out anything or had suffered from similar errors, please share your knowledge.

UPDATE ! :

Here is var_dump($this->params); from booksController.php:

```
object(CakeRequest)#6 (9) {
["params"]=>
array(5) {
["plugin"]=>
NULL
["controller"]=>
string(5) "books"
["action"]=>
string(5) "index"
["named"]=>
array(0) {
}
["pass"]=>
array(0) {
}
}
["data"]=>
array(2) {
["signed_request"]=>
string(514) "//here is a very long string hash"
["locale"]=>
string(5) "en_GB"
}
```

(I didn't paste the whole var_dump() here because lots of unnecessary information)

So what I understood is that I need to somehow validate that signed_request from Facebook to get my website working in Facebook canvas? I just don't have any clue how to do that... I have implemented "my own" admin authentication system with Auth-components. I know that I would need to fix something from there, but I somehow don't know where to start. Too much moving parts...

Is the approach presented in the answer below correct one? At least it fixed that problem, but mine it didn't. What I mean is, what is the key element in that answer which I can transfer to my code? Or if I only get a full picture, I would find out myself the answer...

SECOND UPDATE ! :

I unset($this->request->data['signed_request']) and then $this->Security->csrfCheck = false... didn't work. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The "blackhole" is due to your [Security Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html).  I believe your issue has been resolved at this question/answer:  [CakePHP and Facebook with Security Component turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820883/cakephp-and-facebook-with-security-component-turned-on)

Comment: Thanks for this! That other post didn't solve the problem, but now I definitely know where to look for solutions. It is surely Security component related problem. @Dave